# Using CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application') causes "Server execution failed" error when run as administrator

Tags: delphi, outlook, delphi-xe2

It's a Delphi XE2 app. Pretty simple. Just calls CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application') and assigns the result to a Variant.

If the program is run as administrator it fails with "Server execution failed", but it works fine and I can get the version number back if I run as the logged in user (without elevated permissions).

Why is this? What is it about running as administrator that stops it from creating the object?

Comment: Did you check the System Event Log to see if the failure was logged with more info?

Comment: Do you run Outlook on the server side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is due to a mismatch between the security contexts. Outlook is a singleton, so `CreateOleObject` will connect to the running instance of Outlook if it is available. COM system refuses to marshal calls between processes with different security contexts.

Either make sure Outlook is not running when calling `CreateOleObject` or make sure both processes run in the same security context.

You can also switch to Extended MAPI (which is a set of dlls loaded in-proc) used directly or through a wrapper (such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects roughly corresponds to the `Namespace` object in the Outlook Object Model.).